# Synchronise configs on all my systems

Tags: linux, sync

I am looking for a tool that would "*make all my (linux) systems look the same*". What I mean by this, is that I use many programs that put some kind of global config file in my local home folder. Say `~/.vimrc` for Vim. I am used to my settings and I get extremely annoyed when my configs differ (say on host `A` and `B`). For Vim, I have a git repository which takes care of it, but it would be cumbersome to create a repository for each program, and it would probably break if I had *ALL* configs in the same repository (for instance, the `~/.synergy.conf` must be *slightly* different on different hosts, but very similar on most).

So, before I start designing and writing something like this, I was wondering if somebody knows a tool that is flexible enough to specify how a configuration file can be adapted automatically for different systems (my low-end approach would be some Makefiles and a git repository, but there must be something more sophisticated, right?).

From the top of my head, some examples could be: Vim (`.vim/`+`.vimrc`), Git (`.gitconfig`), Opera (`.opera/???`), List of installed packages, OpenSSH (`.ssh/config`) but the list goes on endlessly.

Comment: By "list of installed packages" do you mean you want applictions that are installed to be installed to all devices automatically?

Comment: @Paul: Ideally it would somehow ask, or simply point out which are missing. I realise this needs superuser privileges, which I only have on some machines (but not all). Again, what I want is flexibility (for example, when setting up the synch tool for a host, I could tell it to either automatically install missing packages or to ignore them).

Comment: Well the config parts are relatively easy using rsync.  Are all the machines running the same distribution - which one?  For the machines I have that are permanently on the same network, I just use a shared /home over nfs.

Comment: Your approach does not work for laptops (which may be without network/internet access), also sharing one `/home` is way too strict for my taste. Besides, I do not own all machines, and on some my user name is different and I have not root access. As I said, the data isn't exactly the same, but it is quite similar. I'm probably going to tailor something with Makefiles and a bunch of scripts, but I wanted to check that I'm not reinventing the wheel (I hate that).

Answer (score 0):

As for config files I use dropbox and soft links.

I have a dropbox dir called config and I move there all the files I want to keep in sync. In my computers I remove all those config files, and I just link to the copy in Dropbox/config.

ie, if I want to have always the same .vimrc:

In the computer I know I have the good one:

```
$ mv ~/.vimrc ~/Dropbox/config/vimrc
$ ln -s ~/Dropbox/config/vimrc ~/.vimrc
```

In all the other computers:

```
$ rm ~/.vimrc
$ ln -s ~/Dropbox/config/vimrc .vimrc
```

Notice I like to store the hidden files without the initial dot in Dropbox.

In addition you could put the dropbox config dir in git if you want to keep version control.